# JavaFX image getUrl() causing NoSuchMethodError in Excelsior jet

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, compilation

I'm trying to compile my javaFx application using Excelsior Jet and it worked fine except for when i used getUrl() on Type javafx.scene.image.Image,
this method exists and it works when i run the application from eclipse, but when I run it in excelsior i get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: getUrl
```

I'm not sure how it works but I thought that something might be missing from excelsior's libraries, is there any way to work around this problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look up the documentation of this method

[docs for getUrl()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html#getUrl())

you will see, that this method was introduced in Java 9 and I assume that Excelsior Jet is still based on Java 8.

Comment: i checked the docs and that's completely right, your answer doesn't solve the problem but it answers my question so i will accept it, but i really need some hack through this

Comment: Can't you just remember the URL string which you passed to the constructor or did you create the image from FXML? If you created the image from a stream, the missing method would return null anyway.

Comment: no i created the image using a File, and yes that's a great idea i will try this

Comment: i found a solution and posted it as an answer, thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution to this problem based on this suggestion ["just remember the URL"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52027052/javafx-image-geturl-causing-nosuchmethoderror-in-excelsior-jet/52027120?noredirect=1#comment91005415_52027120), by creating a new class named Image that extends javafx.scene.image.Image and gave it a new url attribute and a method to get it

```
public class Image extends javafx.scene.image.Image{

    String url;

    public Image(String url) {
        super(url);
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String geturl() {
        return url;
    }

}
```

and then calling geturl() instead of getUrl() (because i can't override the final method getUrl() ).